# A Bit Shift-like function or algorithm that returns four bytes output of numbers input

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Hello I have being trying to develop a C++ function or algorithm that behaves like bit shifting the function will always return 4 byte  `00 00 00 00` of any number input ranging from `0` to `99999999`

input (int) -> expected output (char or string)

```
0 -> 00 00 00 00
20 -> 00 00 20 00
200 -> 00 02 00 00
2000 -> 00 20 00 00
99999999-> 99 99 99 99
```

and can be reversed to return original numbers.

input (char or string)-> expected output (int/double)

```
00 00 20 00 -> 20
00 02 00 00 -> 200
00 20 00 00 -> 2000
99 99 99 99 -> 99999999
```

**EDIT**:

This is the code I have.  It came close to what am looking for but still work in progress:

```
void Convert_to_Decimal(std::string str)
{
    double ret;
    ///insert . after string number 6.
    str.insert(5,1,'.');
    str.erase(0, str.find_first_not_of('0'));
    ///remove leading zeros
    ret =std::stod(str.c_str());
    printf("%g\n", ret);
}
```

`Convert_to_Decimal("00020000");`

I will appreciate any pointers or solution to solve this, thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post the code you have written?  It does not seem too difficult, first convert the string to an integer with `strtol`, then parse the decimal part and complete the integer, finally convert the integer to BCD and output the bytes.

Comment: How is `00 00 00 00` 4 bits? If it can contain 8 decimal digits then it is definitely more than 4 bits of information. Also, how is turning an integer into a differently formatted string bit-shifting?

Comment: @kelvinWells i dont know what to call it thats why i said its bitshift-like, more so its 4byte data to be used in a serial port command @chqelie the bcd format of  `20` is `0010 0000` it didn't add up to what i want to achieve

Comment: It looks like it's just BCD with an implicit decimal point. What problems are you having in writing code for this conversion ?

Comment: @PaulR dont even know how to start, i have written a decimal to bcd and versa i can only get the regular bcd conversion `0010 0000` except if there is another way of BCD conversion,but it doesn't come close to his format, still trying to figure out how to write such a function thats why am asking for pointers

Comment: It looks like most of your previous questions are about this same problem ? Some general advice: you probably need to take a step back and make sure you understand the underlying algorithm first - trying to write code for something you don't fully understand is a haphazard approach - see you if you can do it with pencil and paper first, and only then try writing code.

Comment: @PaulR that's very insightful, but i think questions are asked when you have tried and needed to be guided by experienced developers. i have read through the mathematical formulas non add up thats why i brought it hear to get direction or pointers. the Asian team am working with are not just helpful i guess its language barriers and platform target

Comment: It's unclear what algorithm you are specifying. Is it actually "rotate right 2 decimal digits"?  A shift of 2 decimal digits would take `99 99 99 99` to `00 99 99 99`, and also, a shift is not reversible because you lost the information in the 2 lower places.

Comment: Still no [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Describe the input (`int`? 8-character string containing digits, only (decimal separator?)?). Describe the desired output: `four bytes` - great. Containing _what_? Your examples show four groups of two digits: do you want anybody to guess whether that's "hex", or something entirely different? Returned how: `char[]`? `uint_least32_t` - big or little endian? Explain what you mean by _shift_ or leave shift out. Use a telling title with no more than seven significant words. _Reversible conversion between int32 and packed decimal_?

Comment: @greybeard thanks for your addition i have learnt a lot from my recent post on how to express myself and be understood which is what this platform is about. however i have gotten my answer thanks to `chqrlie`, i was only trying to reverse it ans asking is a better way to do that?

Comment: `int` to `string`: Make string from int, insert spaces from end to front (you need to change index after insertion).  If string size != 10 pads zeros and spaces.

`string` to `int` should be trivial (just delete spaces and do `string` to `int`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
#include <stdint.h>

/* encode a number given as a string into a 4 byte buffer */
void number_convert(unsigned char *dest, const char *str) {
    uint32_t v = 0;
    while (*str >= '0' && *str <= '9') {
        /* parse digits and encode as BCD */
        v = (v << 4) + (*str++ - '0');
    }
    /* make room for 2 decimal places */
    v <<= 8;
    if (*str == '.') {
        if (str[1] >= '0' && str[1] <= '9') {
            /* set number of tenths */
            v += (str[1] - '0') << 4;
            if (str[2] >= '0' && str[2] <= '9') {
                /* set number of hundredths */
                v += (str[2] - '0');
            }
        }
    }
    /* store the BCD value in big endian order */
    dest[0] = (v >> 24) & 255;
    dest[1] = (v >> 16) & 255;
    dest[2] = (v >>  8) & 255;
    dest[3] = (v >>  0) & 255;
}

void test(const char *str) {
    unsigned char buf[4];

    number_convert(buf, str);
    printf("%s -> %02X %02X %02X %02X\n", str, buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3]);
}

int main(void) {
    test("0");
    test("20");
    test("200");
    test("2000");
    test("123.1");
    test("999999.99");
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

Your code uses a `float` variable.  Your question is unclear: do you want to compute 4 bytes?  To do this, you should use a byte array, otherwise, please expand with a more precise explanation for chat you are trying to achieve.

To perform the conversion from your 4 byte digit array back to a number, you can do this:

```
double convert_BCD_to_double(unsigned char *str) {
    long res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        res = res * 100 + (str[i] >> 4) * 10 + (str[i] & 15);
    }
    return (double)res / 100;
}
```

Comment: @MelFzlic: does this answer fit your needs?

Comment: i have being away on a short trip, i have tried to modify your function i have but being trying to figure your code return value is `int` no return sign so i changed it to `void` but still am unable to sort it out can you provide me with use case? thanks

Comment: @MelFzllc: good point regarding the return type.  I added some testing code.  Did you mean for `99999999` to produce `99 99 99 99`?  Shouldn't `999999.99` produce that?

Comment: The above code answers your original question.  You edited it to remove the decimal point handling, shouldn't you also change the examples, such as `200 -> 00 00 02 00` etc.

Comment: thanks, your function did work, thanks for your patience also, i was working with a team mate who must have updated the values.  i will sure start working on  reversing the process to get the decimal number with your pointers

Comment: the code is to show to show what i was expecting in bytes so that anyone could guide me on what to do

Comment: this is my code for string to double `00 00 02 00-> 2.00` i want to to look at it and suggest if there is a better way to do it  void `void ConvertBCDToDecimal(std::string str)
{
    double ret;
    ///insert . after string number 6.
    str.insert(5,1,'.');
    str.erase(0, str.find_first_not_of('0'));
    ///remove leading zeros
    ret =std::stod(str.c_str());
    printf("%f\n", ret);
}`

Comment: @MelFzllc: I updated my answer. The 4 byte BCD encoded arrays are not really C++ `std::strings`.  Choose one language, C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: am actually coding with c++, but thanks you have being helpful to me on this project am new to raw data and hadware input manuplulation.

Comment: hello, i am getting this value `1e+006` instead of `999999.99` using this function `convert_BCD_to_double(unsigned char *str)` with entry value of  `99 99 99 99` just wondering if you have any pointers.

Comment: @MelFzllc: How do you convert the number? What `printf` format did you use? Do you store it in a `float`?

Comment: i started losing precision from here `unsigned char bbbb[4] = {0x09,0x99,0x99,0x99};` other values from `unsigned char bbbb[4] = {0x00,0x99,0x99,0x99};` below works just fine.

Comment: i solve it, it was just the printing format issue afterall `printf("double value %0.2f\n",dblv);` or `cout.precision(8);` sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

For integers, let us define shifting as multiplying or dividing the number by its representation base.
For decimal, a shift right:
  `300 --> 30`
hexadecimal:
  `0x345 --> 0x34`
binary:
  `1101 --> 110`

For decimal, shifting right one digit requires dividing by 10.  For hexadecimal, divide by 16 and for binary, divide by 2.

Shifting left is multiplying by the base:  decimal - multiply by 10, hexadecimal by 16 and binary by 2.

When the shift goes beyond the edges of the number, you cannot restore the original number by shifting the other direction.

For example, shifting 345 right one digit yields 34.  There is no way to get the 5 back by shifting left one digit.  The common rule is when a number is shifted, a new digit of 0 is introduced.  Thus 34 shifted left one digit yields 340.

Regarding your floating point.  I don't see how the bytes 99 99 99 99 produces 999999.99.  Is the last byte *always* to the right of the decimal point?

For shifting bytes, use the operators << and >>.  You want to use the largest size integer that contains your byte quantity, such as `uint32_t` for 4 byte values.  Also, use `unsigned` numbers because you don't want the *signed* representation to interfere with the shifting.

**Edit 1: Example functions**

```
uint32_t Shift_Left(unsigned int value, unsigned int quantity)
{
  while (quantity > 0)
  {
    value = value * 2;
  }
  return value;
}

uint32_t Shift_Left(unsigned value, unsigned int quantity)
{
  return value << quantity;
}
```

For shifting by bytes, set quantity to 8 or multiples of 8 (8 bits per byte).